# How to pull numbers from a string with curly brackets?

Tags: php, regex

I have a test string which is something like this:

```
digit{digit}digit
```

I want to break this string into 3 variables.  For example, `40{1}2` should be split into 40 1 2.  The string could be as big as `2034{345}1245`. I assume regex would be the best way to split this string.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$productID = preg_match('/(.*?){/', $product);
$productOptionID = preg_match('/{(.*?)}/', $product);
$optionValueID = preg_match('/}(.*?)/', $product);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for regular expressions here:

```
$str = '40{1}2';

sscanf($str, '%d{%d}%d', $part_1, $part_2, $part_3);
// $part_1 would equal: 40
// $part_2 would equal: 1
// $part_3 would equal: 2
```

With this method, the variables are already typecast to integers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
preg_match('/^(\d+)\{(\d+)\}(\d+)$/', '123{456}789', $matches)
$productId = $matches[1];
$productOptionId = $matches[2];
$productValueId = $matches[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [preg_split](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) :

```
$str = '123{456}789';
$arr = preg_split("/[{}]/", $str);
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 456
    [2] => 789
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally create a simple function that can manage the process of fetching the data from the string like so:

```
function processID($string)
{
    $result = array();
    $c = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {
         if(!isset($result[$c]))
         {
             $result[$c] = "";
         }

         if($string[$i] == "{" || $string[$i] == "}")
         {
             $c++;
             continue;
         }

         $result[$c] .= $string[$i];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and then just use like:

```
$result = processID("2034{345}1245");
```

The outputted result would be like so:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "2034"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "345"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "1245"
}
```

and a working example can be found here: http://codepad.org/7k5tAzuy